# Every irreducible component of an affine cone contains its vertex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, affine-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $X=V(F_1,...,F_k)\subset \mathbb{P}^n$with $F_i\in k[X_0,...,X_n]$ an projective algebraic set. Let $C(X)\in \mathbb{A}^{n+1}$ the affine cone over $X$, that is

$C(X)=\theta^{-1}(X)\cup \{(0,...,0)\}$

where $\theta:\mathbb{A}^{n+1}\setminus \{(0,...,0)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ is defined by $P\to \bar{P}$

I want to show that every irreducible component of the cone contains the vertex $(0,...,0)$. 
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This corresponds to the fact that any ideal generated by homogeneous polynomials is the intersection of *homogeneous* ideals. That is, if you know this (or see how to prove it), your claim will follow (because if every component is defined by homogeneous ideals, clearly $(0,\ldots,0)$ lies in every component).

Here's another way. Note that $C(X)$ comes with a natural $k^\ast$-action. For any $P \in C(X)$, the point $tP$ also lies in $C(X)$ for $t \neq 0$. Since $C(X)$ is closed, it follows that $0 \in C(X)$.

Now write $C(X) = \cup_{i=1}^n X_i$ as a union of irreducible components. I claim that there is a subgroup $L^\ast \subset k^\ast$ such that $L^\ast$ act on the $X_i$. Now since $k^\ast$ act on $C(X)$, it must permute the $X_i$. But since there are only $n$ components, all the elements $c^n$ must fix $X_i$. Hence the subgroup $\{ c^n \mid c \in k ^\ast \}$ act on each $X_i$ individually.

Each of the irreducible components are closed. Consider $P \in X_0$. Then $\{ tP \mid t \in k \}$ is an irreducible closed set contained in $X$ (it is a line), that intersects $X_0$. Now the $k^\ast$-action restrict to an action on $X_0$, so the whole line must be contained in $X_0$ since $X_0$ is closed.

**Remark** Note that if $k^\ast$ is a divisible group (for example if $k=\mathbb C^\ast$), then we can take $L=\mathbb C$.

Comment: "But X_0 is an irreducible component, so the whole line must line in X_0" why ?

Comment: @user44636 I notice I wasnt very clear when I wrote this. Because of the $k^\ast$-action, we have automatically that $\{ tP \mid t \in k^\ast \}$ is contained in $X_0$. But since $X_0$ is closed, it follows that it contains $(0,0,0...0)$.

Comment: Dear Fredrik, it's still not clear for me why line $tP$ should be contained in the $X_0$? Why the line couldn't just intersect $X_0$ at one point?

Comment: @user44636 Thank you for the comment again. I have added more details to my answer (in fact, it is probably a different answer now). Do you think it makes more sense?

Comment: Fredrik, maybe it's annoying, but I'm still confused by the statement: 
"Now since $k^*$ act on $C(X)$, it must permute the $X_i$", it should be indeed the case, but could you clarify this, please?

Comment: @user44636 No, it's not annoying at all, these questions got me thinking. About your last question: multiplying by $c \in k^\ast$ leaves $C(X)$ invariant, and hence the decomposition into irreducible components is the same. Then, since $c \cdot C(X) = \cup c \cdot X_i = C(X)$, and the decomposition is unique, we must have $c \cdot X_i = X_j$ for some $j$.

Comment: Dear, Fredrik !
Now it seems that everything clear to me. 
Thank you!